# When is a Dynamic Port "dynamic"?

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-ports, tcpip

I was having a discussion today about `Dynamic Ports` with one of my co-workers and could use some help clarifying how they work.

**First question:** If the `IPALL` `TCP Dynmaic Ports` setting is a specific number (say 1971) does that signify that you have a static port of 1971 or a dynamic port that is currently 1971 and may change at some point in the future.

[image]

**Second question:** This is the one I'm most curious about.  We have an instance that has had the same port (the value in the `IPALL` `TCP Dynmaic Ports` setting) for several years through dozens of instance restarts.  What actually causes the dynamic port to actually change after an instance restart?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This KB article : [How to configure SQL Server to listen on a specific port](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/823938) will clarify things for you :

**Dynamic Port Allocation**

If you configure an instance of SQL Server to use dynamic port allocation, and you have not yet restarted the instance of SQL Server, the registry values are set as follows:

> TCPDynamicPorts = Blank
>
> TCPPort = 0

However, if you configure an instance of SQL Server to use dynamic port allocation, and you restart the instance of SQL Server, the registry values are set as follows:

> TCPDynamicPorts = Current port that is used
>
> TCPPort = Current port that is used

**Static Port Allocation :**

If you configure an instance of SQL Server to use a static port, and you have not yet restarted the instance of SQL Server, the registry values are set as follows:

> TCPDynamicPorts = Last port that is used
>
> TCPPort = New static port to be used after the next restart; new static port that you set by using the Server Network Utility

However, if you configure an instance of SQL Server to use a static port, and you restart the instance of SQL Server, the registry values are set as follows:

> TCPDynamicPorts = Blank
>
> TCPPort = New static port that you set by using the Server Network Utility

**for your second question** -

Every time you start the named SQLServer, it uses the port that is allocated. **In case if the port is used by another program**, then SQL Server chooses another port at the time of restart i.e. The dynamic port is chosen at first startup, and will **generally remain the same** through future restarts (stored in the Registry) - but if its used by another program then SQL server will choose a new port. note: For Prod Servers, I use only static ports - security and ease of manageability reasons.

Note: More cools thing to find out :

Check if Dynamic port is being used or not using T-SQL :

```
SELECT NAME
    ,protocol_desc
    ,type_desc
    ,state_desc
    ,is_admin_endpoint
    ,port
    ,is_dynamic_port
    ,ip_address
FROM sys.tcp_endpoints
```

[image]

You can use  `netstat -ano` to check using cmdline.

Additionally, you can check what got cached earlier in the registry on the client side as to what port it is using to connect to sql server :

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\Client\SNI11.0\LastConnect
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks and that is a very useful link!  Do you know what causes a dynamic port to change ports?  See `Second question` in my question above.

Comment: @KennethFisher for your `second question` -  Every time you start the named SQLServer, it uses the port that is allocated. **In case if the port is used by another program** then SQL Server chooses another port at the time of restart. The dynamic port is chosen at first startup, and will generally remain the same through future restarts (stored in the Registry) - but if its used by another program then SQL server will choose a new port. **note**: For Prod Servers, I use **only** static ports - security and ease of manageability reasons.

Comment: Would you be so kind to explain why do you think it is worth to implement completely new service ( SQL server browser) which is working on **static** port so it may not start if this port is used, just because you want to start SQL server in a case where some other services are using ports you are too clumsy to attach to probably the most expensive software you are using?