# MS SQL Server IP address change considerations

Tags: sql-server, migration

I am very new to MS SQL Server Administration and wants to learn on Migration of SQL Server in detail. We are in a Datacenter migration Project where the Windows server (SQL Server is residing in it) is going to be migrated AS-IS from Source to Destination. I would like to know what are the things that we need to take care for the SQL Server IP address connectivity issues and other related connectivity problems. correct me if anything wrong in framing the question and thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you are just changing IP address ONLY, then there are less things to worry.

Check

- Change the IP address and restart SQL Server.
- If your applications are referencing IP address instead of HOST, then they need to change their web.config files to reflect the new IP address.
- Linked servers referencing IP address needs to be changed as well.
- If any user workstations are connecting using IP, then they need to `flush DNS` using `ipconfig /flushdns` or better just restart their workstations.
- If the server is part of [Failover cluster then follow this steps as well](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190460.aspx).

If you want to be proactive and find out the applications connecting to your sql server instance, then use **[this server side trace](https://gist.github.com/TheRockStarDBA/31d781b0fae1de40d0aa)** and then plan accordingly for downtime.

Note: *make sure you assign a [**static IP address and port to sql server**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/47656/8783).*

Comment: If the IP is registered in a DNS server, it also helps to reduce TTL to a couple minutes or X seconds a couple days before and revert it back to its original value after the IP change.