# When to use a TCP dynamic port and when TCP Port?

Tags: sql-server, security, connectivity, sql-server-2017, dynamic-ports

I have a new server that is configured using a dynamic port as you can see below:

[image]

The application that connects to this server uses the following connection string, but I am getting the following error:

[image]

I asked the developer to change the connection port from 61844 to 53187, which is my dynamic port.

After done that and restarting their services, the application could connect to SQL Server.

Is there any specific reason it needs to be using a dynamic port?

Comment: Does this help https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/47656/8783 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say that something else uses the port that you have configured for your SQL Server: What do you prefer? 
The SQL Server to start but use a different port? Use dynamic. 
Not start at all? Use static.

Another aspect is that your developers seem to have hard-wired the port number in the application (connection string) i.e., connect to something e.g. `yourserver,45346`. That is one way to do it. Another way is to connect using the instance name such as `yourserver\instancename`. This way the port resolution is handled for you, but it requires that the SQL Server browser service is started on the server machine and you can reach it using UDP port 1434 for the name->portnumber "query".

Comment: Often people revert to `server,port` when they can't (or can't be bothered to) figure out why the translation isn't handled for them (usually browser service is not running or network protocols are not enabled).

Comment: @AaronBertrand you add meaningful `details`, TA for being around!

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any specific reason it needs to be using a dynamic port?

There is no good reason to continue using a dynamic port.  They are used by default for named instances because there is no well-known port for SQL Server other than 1433, and so the only reliable way to open a listening port is to pick an available one at startup.

You should routinely pick fixed port for each instance to enable clients to connect without an instance name, and without using the SQL Browser service.

Comment: What's the reason for the defaults? (dynamic) And what's the reason that this can't be configured with the setup? Is there any good explanation for that? Thanks

Comment: Named instance use dynamic ports because port 1433 is reserved for the default instance.  Multiple instances were introduced in SQL Server 2000, and had to find a way to extend the existing behavior from when only a single instance was allowed.  Thus the whole idea of a "default" instance and a "named" instance.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. I think it would be cool if the first named instance could be on 1433 by default too if there is no default instance installed ☺️